# is there a simple example how to send emails using Tornado?

Tags: smtp, tornado

sorry for this question,

i just need a simple example to understand how SMTP works with Tornado;

What do i need, if i've a simple application, then do i need to open a new account on Gmail or Yahoo?

Answer (score 1):

Tornado doesn't provide anything to handle SMTP.

You can use [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html), although it's synchronous. [Check out the example given](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example).

Comment: yes, as you said it is sadly synchronous, i need a way how to use tornado in the simplest way

Comment: tornado is not thread safe (Python GIL + the nature of event-driven architecture).

Comment: You can use a thread as long as it doesn't have anything to do with the IOLoop. Just transfer data back with `IOLoop.add_callback`.

Comment: However, there's a better strategy I didn't think of – write it to the  database, and have another (synchronous) script read the db and actually send the email.

Comment: but it will be always a blocking operation (sending them)?

Comment: smtplib is. There are alternatives (e.g. https://github.com/philwhln/tornado-smtp-client) but all are alpha at best.

Comment: Here is a threading example (from the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576829/tornado-non-blocking-smtp-client): https://github.com/marcinc81/quemail/blob/master/quemail.py

Comment: the tornado-smtp-client does not support (as the example) using gmail smtp server, and quemail seems a little bit complicated.